# How to delete xml node from ntext column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a column of type `ntext`. This column contains xml as string

I want to delete one element that can exists more than once.

How do I do that?

Example xml input:

```
<CATALOG>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>Hide your heart</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Bonnie Tyler</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>CBS Records</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1988</YEAR>
    </CD>
</CATALOG>
```

I want to delete the node `COUNTRY` with a SQL update script

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx). And if your column really contains XML - you should really use the `XML` datatype in SQL Server 2005 and newer

Comment: If your column really is `ntext` (which should never be) its contents is just a chunk of text. There is no way other than parse it and remove the nodes on your own. The best solution is to change it to `xml` column and use specialized methods, but if that's not possible, I suppose the next best alternative is to do it client-side, using dedicated xml parsing functions.

Comment: unfortunately is it ntext. its an old database and i cannot change the colum to a different type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to do this, then you have to

- load the data into a SQL variable of type `XML`
- perform the modification on that variable
- update your table again

So you need to do something like this:

```
DECLARE @XmlVar XML

SELECT @XmlVar = CAST(YourNtextColumn AS XML)
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE ID = 123

SET @XmlVar.modify('delete /CATALOG//CD/COUNTRY')

SELECT @XmlVar
```

Now in the end, you'd have to write back the modified XML variable to your table. The trouble is: you cannot convert from `XML` to `NTEXT` ...... so you  should **really** fix your table structure first (make that column a `XML` in the first place!) before wasting your time trying to update this deprecated column type...

Comment: Thanks for the answers.  
I have made an SQL command to delete the node i want.